# 404 Not Found On A Post Route

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, http-post

I Am Sending A Post Request To This Route But It Is Not Working And Sending Me A 404 Not Found
Here Is The Code For The Route

```
app.post('/case/new', (req, res) => {
    Case.create({
        name: req.query.name,
        paid: req.query.paid,
        assigned: req.query.assigned,
        description: req.query.description,
        date: req.query.date,
    }, (err, created) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.send(created)
        }
    })
})
```

And I Am Sending The Request Using jQuery
here Is The jQuery Code

```
 
$.ajax({
     url: 'https://modern-clinic.herokuapp.com/new/case',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
         name: this.state.name,
         description: this.state.desc,
         paid: this.state.paid,
         assigned: this.state.assigned,
         date: this.state.date
      }
})
```

Comment: One is `/case/new` the other is `/new/case`...?

Comment: But It Is Not Sending Query Strings

Comment: After I Fixed It

Comment: Why would it send querystrings? You're making a POST request

Comment: Because I Don't Know How To Send In The `request body` Itself

Comment: That's my point, you *are* sending the data in the request body.

Comment: I Understand You But I Don't Know How

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://modern-clinic.herokuapp.com/new/case',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        name: this.state.name,
        description: this.state.desc,
        paid: this.state.paid,
        assigned: this.state.assigned,
        date: this.state.date
    }
})
```

Comment: If you get 404 error it means that you try to post on url that not exists. Please check which exact url you should provide for $POST. '/case/new' or '/new/case'